# clojure for function resets let

Tags: variables, for-loop, clojure, let

I am trying to solve a problem on [4clojure.com](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/22#prob-title) where I'm supposed to count the number of elements in a collection without using `count`. I have tried two ways using `for` and `let` that I feel should work but it seems that the for-loop keeps resetting the `let`.

```
(#(for [x %  :let [y 0]] (inc y)) [1 2 3 4 5])
;; which returns
(1 1 1 1 1)

(#(let [y 0] (for [x %] (inc y))) [1 2 3 4 5])
;; which returns
(1 1 1 1 1)
```

So my question is why this happens, and how I get my "variable" to keep incrementing for each item in the collection. Just saying the word variable makes me wonder if I'm trying to make something muteable that can't, but I still feel like this should work.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind as you are learning clojure is that `for` is not a looping construct -- it's a list comprehension, for creating lists. So, when you want to actually loop, it's usually best to use `loop`. Looking back at this one, I used `reduce`, which, besides pure recursion, is the most "functional programming" way to approach the problem (more so than an explicit loop, I mean). Cheers and have fun!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in both cases you can't alter the value of `y`:

in first case `for` re-introduces the `y` on every loop step, that's why you couldn't change it's value, even if it was mutable.

the second case shows that the value is truly immutable, giving you `(inc y)` on every step, but `y` is always zero. Simple example:

```
(let [x 10]
  (inc x)
  x)

;;=> 10
```

In general this kind of task can usually be solved with the following approaches:

First one is the simple recursion:

```
(defn count-rec [data]
  (if (seq data)
    (inc (count-rec (rest data)))
    0))

user> (count-rec [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> 5
```

it is flawed in a way, since it is not tail recursive, and would fail for large collections

The second one is clojure's `loop`:

```
(defn count-loop [data]
  (loop [res 0 data data]
    (if (seq data)
      (recur (inc res) (rest data))
      res)))

user> (count-loop [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> 5
```

also you can use explicit tail recursion which would be very alike:

```
(defn count-tailrec
  ([data] (count-tailrec 0 data))
  ([c data] (if (seq data)
              (recur (inc c) (rest data))
              c)))

user> (count-tailrec [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> 5
```

The third one would use the `reduce` function:

```
(defn count-reduce [data]
  (reduce (fn [res _] (inc res)) 0 data))

user> (count-reduce [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> 5
```

Just for fun you could also use this way (i would not advice it, since it is an overkill in comparison with `reduce`):

```
(defn count-map [data]
  (apply + (map (constantly 1) data)))

user> (count-map [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> 5
```

You could also use clojure's mutable primitives, but it is not idiomatic, and should be avoided for as long as it could be:

```
(defn count-atom [data]
  (let [c (atom 0)]
    (run! (fn [_] (swap! c inc)) data)
    @c))

user> (count-atom [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> 5
```

**and here comes the cheat [SPOILER ALERT!]**

> 4clojure blocks the usage of `count` function in this task, but doesn't block the `.size` method of java's collections, so it could be solved with
> `#(.size (seq %))`

Comment: Amazing answer! I found the use of `reduce` and `loop/recur` to be the easiest to apply mentally for this specific problem, but the other examples were really helpful to better understand how to look at the problem in different ways.

Comment: @Thumbnail : what do you mean? there is this exact variant in the answer (look at `count-reduce`)

Comment: @leetwinski missed it.